# Windows Server 2008 access backup data partition

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-backup

I am trying to figure out how to manually copy the Windows Server 2008 backup partition to a Samba share.  The purpose is to consolidate several machines worth of backup data into one location for writing to a tape drive.

I have an automated task which creates the daily backup, however I can't specify the location for the backup as the Samba share, because Samba doesn't allow System users access.

Thus, my idea is create a shell script which is invoked as an automated Task Schedule and performs the copy as a non-System user.

However, I can't figure out how to access the hidden data partition of the backup.  I see in the Backup Entry the partition name, but can't figure out how to access it.

[edit: I have not created this partition, nor chosen it.  It is the default location which Windows Server Backup writes to.]

Comment: When you say 'backup partition', are you referring to a partition you created and are putting backups into? or are you referring to the recovery partition?

Comment: good point.  I'll update the question -- I'm have not created this partition, it is whatever magical location Windows Backup writes to.

Comment: Are you talking about using the Windows Backup application? Or are you talking about the Backup utility you can use from the Hard Drive properties?

Comment: this is in relation to the Windows Backup application, yes.  sorry for being unclear.  Not much of a Windows'er

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Windows Backup utility, you should be allowed to select a location from the Windows Backup Wizard.  You can do this by:

1. Going to 'Start'
2. Clicking 'Control Panel'
3. Clicking 'System and Maintenance'
4. Clicking 'Backup and Restore'
5. Editing the appropriate task to pick a new location for your backups

If you're talking about the volume shadow copy (VSS) partition (the backups and versioning files), then my recommendation would be to:

1. Add a new hard drive specifically for volume shadow copy
2. Migrate all volume shadow copy from all drives to the spare drive

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364933(WS.10).aspx

Alternatively, you should be able to store your VSS onto a SBM share without issues:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612865.aspx

If you run into problems using an SMB share, you can mount an SMB share to your system as a local disk and that should allow you to store your VSS data there.

Comment: So, I see in the WSB utility I have the option to specify the location, however I can't see where it is currently writing to.  If I change it, then setting it back would result in the drive being formatted.

Comment: Then that's not how your backups are kicked off.  Did you set up the backups or did you adopt them?

Comment: Previous admin already had the backup configured.  I can manually schedule a backup and I think I get the same options as were used for the existing daily scheduled backup.

Comment: Chances are, it's a scheduled task.  Check your scheduled tasks for backup batch/scripts.  These should be editable, and if you read the batch/script, you should be able to identify the location of the backups.

Comment: Looking into Task Scheduler I see the backup task.  It runs "wbadmin start backup -tempID:{.....} -quiet    But i don't see any storage location listed.\

Comment: Please copy the whole script into your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25883/discussion-between-daniel-and-cia).

Comment: I don't have a script ... WBM backup is being run by Task Scheduler which I'm sure has an internal recorded, but nothing I created.  Also, the machine is not networked - I can't copy/paste from it.

Comment: Unless I can see the script, I can't really tell you anything more.  You might just have to write it all down?  It shouldn't be more than 1 or 2 lines of code.

Comment: but ... what script?  I don't know what script you are referring to.   I've only used the WBA GUI to create a backup entry. here are the settings:  everyday at 9pm run "wbamin.exe start backup -templateId:{GUID}"  ... I'm not transcribing the actual guid, I don't think that is the relevant bit.

Comment: what's the ... for?

Comment: emphasizing my confusion of what script?

Comment: If that's the whole script being used to backup your system, then it's backing up to VSS.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc742083.aspx  Since that's the case, you can migrate the VSS by following the link I provided above.  See this reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc742083.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  So,  using the default of the backup location given in the link and using the GUID from the templiateID as a sharename I am prompted for creds, but mine aren't excepted.  I'm guessing it's a system user directory ...  not sure how I'll be able to read from there (assuming it's the correct location).

Comment: Only use `templateid` if you're using a template.  Otherwise, build your script specifically for what you want to back up and identify where you want it backed up to.  You need to run the script as an admin.  See this for reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd767786.aspx

Comment: alright thanks for you help.  I'll let this puppet rest :).

Answer (score 0):

If you're selecting a disk as the backup location for Windows Server Backup then WSB effectively takes over that disk and doesn't allow user access to that disk. It removes it from Disk Management (AFAIK) so it won't show up there nor in Windows/File Explorer. You're going to have to select a network share (other than your Samba share) as your backup target if you want to copy the backups to your Samba share.